# Geometry - Straight lines and triangles

Tags: triangles

Let ABCD be a quadrilateral and X be the midpoint of BD .Prove that the area of AXCB is one half area of ABCD.

The problem seems really easy ,however i am not able to prove it for any quadrilateral ,for  parallelograms it is very simple

Can someone please help

Comment: Use coordinate geometry for starting

Comment: If you are familiar with the concept of area vector use it

Comment: Hint. Using $\overline{BX}$ and $\overline{DX}$ for bases, triangles $AXB$ and AXD$ have the same altitudes...